# Can I use my birth certificate as identification on a bus in Texas?

Tags: usa, buses, identity-cards, texas

I'm 17 and I am traveling from Laredo (Texas, US) to San Antonio (Texas). I don't have an ID, but I do have my birth certificate. Can I use that to travel by bus in Texas?

Comment: You may consider to look up the information to both questions on the website of the bus service provider. Rules do vary from provider to provider.

Comment: I updated your question, to contain only one. However, for it to be re-opened, more information is needed, such as the bus service provider.

Comment: Which bus line? I don't know that I've ever even been asked to show ID when taking a bus, except maybe when I ordered a ticket online, and had to show my ID to pick it up at will call (although I know even that isn't consistent).

Answer (score 3):

According to this [page](http://www.greyhound.com/en/ticketsandtravel/TermsAndConditions.aspx#ImportantInformation), if you are using Greyhound and you are buying a ticket online, you will need photo identification. Therefore, I believe that your birth certificate will not be enough. Here is the relevant excerpt (emphasis is mine):

> Each passenger must present a ticket and a *valid photo ID* to board the bus.